# Problemas con DropDownList ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Saludos, tengo problemas con un DropDownList en ASP.net MVC, la página web filtra los Profesores pero a la hora de guardar da el siguiente error:

Este es el error que muestra el Sistema:

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Line 61:                 ViewBag.ProfesorId = new SelectList(db.Profesors, "ProfesorId", "name", materia.ProfesorId);

Mi Codigo en el Model:
Materia.cs

```
public class Materia
{
   [Key]
   public int MateriaId { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [Display(Name ="Materia")]
   public string materia {  get; set; }

    // public string Profesor { get; set; }


   public virtual int ProfesorId { get; set; }
   public virtual Profesor Profesor { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Estudiante> Estudiantes { get; set; }
}
```

en Profesor.cs

```
public class Profesor
{

    public int ProfesorId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Materia> Materias { get; set; }
}
```

en el controlador MateriasController.cs:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include     = "MateriaId,materia,ProfesorId")] Materia materia)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Materias.Add(materia);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        if (materia != null)
        {
            ViewBag.ProfesorId = new SelectList(db.Profesors, "ProfesorId", "name", materia.ProfesorId);
                        }
        return View(materia);
    }
```

en la vista Create.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfesorId,"Profesor", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ProfesorId", ViewBag.ProfesorId as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select Materia", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=> model.ProfesorId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Exacto asi es, pero no entiendo porque, tengo otro modelo/vista/controlador identico y funciona correctamente.

Comment: no, dice esto: db.Profesors = {SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ProfesorId] AS [ProfesorId], 
    [Extent1].[name] AS [name]
    FROM [dbo].[Profesors] AS [Extent1]}, sin embargo el ViewBag viene nulo.

Comment: Si, he insertado en la BD por medio de server explorer.

Comment: como andas aprendiendo sobre ASP.net MVC te recomiendo que le des una visita a un workshop que hice junto con la comunidad de StackOverflow en Español http://fredyfx.com/post/material-workshop-aspnet-mvc-5/ espero te sea de utilidad, saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

**ViewData**

Es un diccionario de objetos al que asignas información, luego esto se convierte accesible en la vista. **ViewData** es un derivado de la clase **ViewDataDictionary**, lo que quiere decir que puedes acceder por la sintaxis de “key/value” o en el buen español: "**clave/valor**" .

**ViewBag**

El objeto ViewBag es una "envoltura" al objeto ViewData que te **permite crear propiedades dinámicas para el ViewBag**.

Parecidos entre ViewBag & ViewData:

1. Ayudan a mantener y enviar datos del controlador a la vista.
2. Tienen una vida corta, es decir, se vuelven null cuando una redirección sucede. Esto pasa porque su meta es proveer una comunicación entre controladores y vistas.

Diferencias entre ViewBag & ViewData:

1. ViewData es un dictionario de objetos derivado de la clase ViewDataDictionary y es accessible usando strings como llaves o claves.
2. ViewBag utiliza propiedades dynamic que toma ventaja de las nuevas características de dynamics en C# 4.0
3. ViewData requiere typecasting para tipos de datos complejos y revisar los valores null para evitar errores.
4. ViewBag no requiere typecasting for tipos complejos de datos.

Ahora, dicha la teoría, vamos con la práctica:

En tu controlador reemplaza:

```
ViewBag.ProfesorId = new SelectList(db.Profesors, "ProfesorId", "name", materia.ProfesorId);
```

Por:

```
ViewBag.ProfesorId = db.Profesors.ToList(); //Para asegurarnos que vienen datos.
```

Y en tu vista prueba con lo siguiente:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProfesorId", new SelectList(ViewBag.ProfesorId, "ProfesorID", "materia"))
```

Comment: Me dio el siguiente error: DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'ProfesorId'.

Comment: aplica un breakpoint en el ViewBag.ProfesorId y mira qué tipo de datos están presentes en la lista y verifica si es lo que estás buscando.

Answer (score 1):

Cambia el tipo de lista por

```
public virtual List<Estudiante> Estudiantes { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sería bueno que revises la [Clase List<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) y el por qué el uso de [covarianza y contravarianza en genéricos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx). Asimismo, tu respuesta es como una recomendación a la pregunta y no llega a la solución de ella.

Answer (score 1):

No el escenario para el uso de ViewBag, te diria una lista en el modelo de tu vista tipada o bien cargarlo por ajax.

Te dejo el link a un post que explica como hacerlo
http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2013/12/aspnet-mvc-carga-dropdownlist.html

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a definir cual es el value y descripción así:

```
ViewBag.ProfesorId = new SelectList(db.Profesors.AsEnumerable(), "ProfesorId", "name");
```